# Finding similar records in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a table with employees, I have a situation where for some records a similar record was created that differs by the country of birth (for one record it should always be the United States, for another it will always be a different country). For example:

| ID | name | surname | date_of_birth | country_of_birth | department_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Anna | Smith | 11/01/1969 | United States | 1 |
| 177 | Anna | Smith | 11/01/1969 | Argentina | 1 |

I would like to find the name of such employee who has such records.
I have tried such SQL (which is bad), but it does not return me any records.

```
Select e1.name,e1.surname from employees.employee e1, employees.employee e2
where e1.name = e2.name
and e1.surname = e2.surname
and e1.country_of_birth <> e2.country_of_birth
```

Please give me a hint on how to write the query properly

Comment: this is not right `e1.name = e2.surname` , you want `e1.name = e2.name`

Comment: @nfgl Yes, of course I should compare. However, no data is returned anyway, and I found manually (by browsing the table) 4 such people

Comment: It works for me after your correction.  Maybe you have invisible characters in your names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use cross join without condition and use departament_id if you need it. Also you have a typo on the conditions. And you would know the Id's

```
Select e1.Id, e2.Id, e1.name,e1.surname from employees.employee e1
cross join employees.employee e2
where e1.name = e2.name
and e1.surname = e2.surname
and e1.country_of_birth <> e2.country_of_birth 
and e1.departament_id = e2.departament_id
```

If you wanna filter only those case that you know are only outside of US:

```
 Select e1.Id, e2.Id, e1.name,e1.surname from employees.employee e1
    cross join employees.employee e2
    where e1.name = e2.name
    and e1.surname = e2.surname
    and e1.country_of_birth <> e2.country_of_birth 
    and e1.departament_id = e2.departament_id
    and e2.country_of_birth <> 'United States'
```

Comment: The SQL query is good, but I have over 600000 records on the database for this department. After 12 minutes, the SQL continued to fail. I'm wondering if I should search for those who have a different birthplace than the US (about 9000 people) and for them see if there are similar entries just with a different birthplace.

Comment: @xampo I don't know your infraestructure situation, but I work with servers with transactions on money that use that amount of records by some hours. In the problem of about the time, is a debate now, but I should do this: 1) not use your local, try to use a server 2) create an index for those fields you will do in conditions 3) you are correct, if you can't do neither of that, or even that, you can divide that hughe work even for country o for year of birth. Divide and conquer! But if you are in a normal server 600k is not so much to that cross join, in a pair of minutes.

Comment: @xampo it will useful also if you had more conditions to compare. If you do a "divide" work, get all the ids and add this condition: AND e1.Id NOT IN(x,x,x,x,x,x,x) where x are your ids

Comment: @xampo sorry, i JUST understand what you mean in your problem. Check my update to the answer. Use e2 as "only not US" virtual table

Comment: @xampo but what about cases when user has 2 records for Argentina and Brazil?